# How can I safely remove contact icons from Twenty-One CV template?

Tags: templates, cv

I am using a modified "twenty seconds" CV template found here:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twentyoneseconds/xmvbqtfmnycf

(simply open in Overleaf for an MWE)

When I try to remove one or more of the contact data (e.g. line 43, cvsitepersonal, it doesn't compile anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, no external links. I suggest you make an MWE and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To omit any of these personal coordinates, leave the contents of the macro empty. Replace e.g.

```
\cvgithub{name-surname-github}
```

by

```
\cvgithub{}
```

Because of an error in `twentyonesecondcv.cls`, this does not work for `\cvsitepersonal`: The icon will remain, with an empty space beside it.

There are two possibilities: work around the error, or fix it.

**Work around:** If you need neither `\cvgithub` nor `\cvsitepersonal`, omitting `\cvgithub` (i.e., writing `\cvgithub{}`) will also let `cvsitepersonal` disappear, problem solved.

**Fix the error:** In the file `twentyonesecondcv.cls`, search for the line

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\cvgithub}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{\Mundus}} & \href{https://\cvsitepersonal}{\textcolor{mainblue}{{\cvsitepersonal}}}\\}
```

and replace `\cvgithub` by `\cvsitepersonal`. Make sure to pick the correct line: The second line starting with `\ifthenelse{\equal{\cvgithub}{}}` needs fixing, while the first one really deals with `cvgithub`. After fixing, `\cvsitepersonal{}` will let the line about the personal website disappear, as it should.